# N_gram frequency python NTLK

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, tf-idf, countvectorizer

I want to write a function that returns the frequency of each element in the n-gram of a given text.
Help please.
I did this code fo counting frequency of 2-gram

code:

```
 from nltk import FreqDist
 from nltk.util import ngrams    
 def compute_freq():
     textfile = "please write a function"
     bigramfdist = FreqDist()
     threeramfdist = FreqDist()
     for line in textfile:
         if len(line) > 1:
             tokens = line.strip().split(' ')
             bigrams = ngrams(tokens, 2)
             bigramfdist.update(bigrams)
      return bigramfdist
  bigramfdist = compute_freq()
```

Comment: What part do you need help with?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Comment: code added @yatu please have a look

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I added my code please have a look

Comment: What is your _specific_ question? How does the posted code fail to do what you want it to?

Comment: I wanted to the frequency of each element in the n-gram

Answer (score 3):

I don't see an expected output section, hence I assume this is what might need.

```
import nltk

def compute_freq(sentence, n_value=2):

    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sentence)
    ngrams = nltk.ngrams(tokens, n_value)
    ngram_fdist = nltk.FreqDist(ngrams)
    return ngram_fdist
```

By default this function returns frequency distribution of bigrams - for example,

```
text = "This is an example sentence."
freq_dist = compute_freq(text)
```

Now, freq_dist would look like -

```
FreqDist({('is', 'an'): 1, ('example', 'sentence'): 1, ('an', 'example'): 1, ('This', 
'is'): 1, ('sentence', '.'): 1})
```

From here you can print the keys and values like so

```
for k,v in freq_dist.items():
    print(k, v) 

('is', 'an') 1
('example', 'sentence') 1
('an', 'example') 1
('This', 'is') 1
('sentence', '.') 1
```

For anything other that bigram, just change the 'n_value' argument when calling the function. For example,

```
freq_dist = compute_freq(text, n_value=3) #will give you trigram distribution

('example', 'sentence', '.') 1
('an', 'example', 'sentence') 1
('This', 'is', 'an') 1
('is', 'an', 'example') 1
```