# Collecting all n-grams (and their frequencies) from document

Tags: python, nltk

I want to collect all n-grams from a text and also their frequencies should be counted. These two challenges can be solved in one or in two python files. This is what I already have. Now this should work for a .txt file instead of putting in the sentence.

```
from nltk import ngrams

sentence = 'Hello, this is an example'

n = 3
threegrams = ngrams(sentence.split(), n)

for grams in threegrams:
  print (grams)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Does [this previous SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58327404/n-gram-frequency-python-ntlk) help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a good answer [here](https://gist.github.com/somyamohanty/12b14dea5fb0f4eedffa) and can break it down for you. Your goal could be met in just one file.

First, import these `nltk` libraries:

```
import nltk
from nltk.collocations import *
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
```

Collocations are expressions of multiple words which commonly co-occur, which is why the `nltk.collocations` library will help with finding their frequencies.
The `word.tokenize` tool is just a different way of performing `sentence.split` that utilizes tools readily available in the nltk package.
(If you get an output error about missing these packages, check [this](https://www.nltk.org/data.html) out)

Here is the sentence I used just to see what my script would do with trigrams:

```
sentence = "Hello, this is an example. This is an example of the trigram count. The trigram count is neat"
```

To instead read a txt file, replace that line with this:

```
myFile = open("file.txt", 'r').read()
```

Next, we are going to tokenize and collocate each trigram:

```
trigram_measures = nltk.collocations.TrigramAssocMeasures()
finder = TrigramCollocationFinder.from_words(word_tokenize(sentence)) 
#for txt files: replace the term 'sentence' with 'myFile'
```

Finally, we print the trigrams and their frequencies:

```
for i in finder.score_ngrams(trigram_measures.raw_freq):
    print(i)
```

`raw_freq` is a method for the [TrigramAssocMeasures() class](https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.TrigramAssocMeasures.html), where you can apply different methods to the trigrams other than frequency.

Here was my output:

```
(('is', 'an', 'example'), 0.09523809523809523)
((',', 'this', 'is'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('.', 'The', 'trigram'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('.', 'This', 'is'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('Hello', ',', 'this'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('The', 'trigram', 'count'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('This', 'is', 'an'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('an', 'example', '.'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('an', 'example', 'of'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('count', '.', 'The'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('count', 'is', 'neat'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('example', '.', 'This'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('example', 'of', 'the'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('of', 'the', 'trigram'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('the', 'trigram', 'count'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('this', 'is', 'an'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('trigram', 'count', '.'), 0.047619047619047616)
(('trigram', 'count', 'is'), 0.047619047619047616)
```